# How to capture output of PSQL command using PG gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg, psql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy data into redshift from s3. While running the following:

```
1.9.2p320 :017 > res = psql_conn.exec("copy table_name from 's3_path' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx' delimiter '|' timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' REMOVEQUOTES NULL AS 'NULLL' MAXERROR AS 500 ACCEPTANYDATE TRUNCATECOLUMNS COMPUPDATE OFF;")
INFO:  Load into table 'table_name' completed, 1 record(s) loaded successfully.
INFO:  Load into table 'table_name' completed, 2 record(s) could not be loaded.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
=> #<PG::Result:0x007ff90b9c6240>
```

My question is how do I capture the INFO: rows into a variable or know if some stl_load_error occured?

Answer (score 0):

These would end up in a log if configured accordingly... I'm pretty certain that you cannot capture them using a variable, short of actually replacing (`$stdout` or) `$stderr` temporarily to something that you can subsequently close and read.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.2.3 you can use [copy_data](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG%2FConnection:copy_data)

```
conn.copy_data "COPY my_table TO STDOUT CSV" do
  while row=conn.get_copy_data
    p row
  end
end
```